# How to generate a unique (random) output path in Pig?

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-pig

Is it possible to generate a unique output folder (s3 bucket), maybe by contacting a random number of some sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround for this case, is to concatenate the current timestamp:

```
%declare cts `date +"%s"`
STORE data INTO '/path/$cts' USING PigStorage();
```

Im not familiar with s3, but the above example show the idea of concatenating random string to get a unique path.